# How two ruby gems can be stored in custom database of rails app?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

When the rails app created and installing ruby gems, I wanted to know how multiple gems integrated and adding custom tables to that
Ex : Social Stream gem, rmagick gem and those database tables to be stored

Comment: I cannot parse your "sentence".

Comment: what should be written

Comment: @Mithun: first, an understandable question must be written. So far, your english has failed you, sadly. You have several answers already, but even their authors are operating on guesses. It's not clear at all, what the question is. Is it "how to add new gems to my app" or what?

Comment: Thanks making me aware of it... while copy pasting from notepad question
missed sentences :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to go trough the gem's official documentation and check how it works internally. You can follow the git hub repos and go through the read me doc and check how it works. Check out its libraries. 
I think if I understood your question then this is the only thing you can do.

Comment: Thanks will go through it once..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to add gems in your app?
Here is how you do it:

Go to your gemfile and add:

```
gem 'social_stream'
gem 'rmagick'
```

You also need to install imagemagick on your system. rmagick requires imagemagick

You can install via yum, apt-get or whatever package manager your OS uses.

One note is that installing imagemagick on OSX is a little tricky. I recommend using homebrew.

Comment: How to combine 2 gems like adding image magix gem in social stream gem and how to add custom fields in social stream.

Comment: first you need to install image magix and then social stream ; for customization read this document http://social-stream.dit.upm.es/started/

Comment: thanks will go through it...